# Why does Bakugou drag Kaminari into the bushes and what did he do to him there?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I don't understand why he drags him off to the bushes to get him to discharge and go into derp mode. Bullying? To recharge the expensive night goggles? To give the rest of the class something to laugh at?

Can any easy assumption be made to what he did to him in the bushes to force discharge?

[image]

Comment: I removed the URL you added as it is not part of the [legal providers](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1458) please keep them in mind with your next post :)

Comment: how much manga does the anime cover?

Comment: This question title is pure clickbait.

Comment: Probably stole his lunch money it seems from the comic.

Comment: Can you give the chapter number?

Comment: @SK19 I suspect chapter 98 based on previous edit history.

Comment: Personally I like to think bakugo was using him as an ATM machine but I don't think that's something kaminari can do.

Comment: @user1821961 But when Kirishima asked "Did you steal Kaminari's money!" Bakugou clearly said that it was his own money.

Answer (score 9):

Because he wanted to distract the class. That was bagugos money, not kaminari’s. He just overcharged kaminari because he was a good and funny distraction while bakougo paid kirishima back. This display of kindness seemed weak to bakougo and he didn’t want the rest of the class seeing it.

Comment: This actually makes sense and fits the character of Bakugo

Answer (score -2):

Because the class's atmosphere was awkward and heavy, so Bakugou decided to make the class (or just his friend Kiri) laugh through Kaminari's derp faces (this is implied from him staring at Kirishima's sullen face before dragging Kaminari off).

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, this is my interpretation of what happened too.

Comment: Based on Bakugo's personality I don't think that was his intention at all.